# The CPU and Memory (value, register)

Tags: memory, copy, cpu, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture

When a value is copied from one register to another, what happens to the value
in the source register? What happens to the value in the destination register.

Answer (score 2):

I'll show how it works in simple processors, like DLX or RISC, which are used to study CPU-architecture.

When  (AT&T syntax, or copy $R1 to $R2)

```
mov $R1, $R2
```

or even (for RISC-styled architecture)

```
add $R1, 0, $R2
```

instruction works, CPU will read source operands: R1 from [register file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_file)  and zero from... may be immediate operand or zero-generator; pass both inputs into [Arithmetic Logic Unit (ALU)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit). ALU will do an operation which will just pass first source operand to destination (because A+0 = A) and after ALU, destination will be written back to register file (but to R2 slot).

So, *Data in source register* is only readed and *not changed* in this operation; *data in destination register will be overwritten* with copy of source register data. (old state of destination register will be lost [with generating of heat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer's_principle).)

At physical level, any register in register file is set of [SRAM cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_RAM), each of them is the two inverters (bi-stable flip-flop, based on M1,M2,M3,M4) and additional gates for writing and reading:

[image: SRAM cell (wiki, PD File:SRAM_Cell_(6_Transistors).svg)]

When we want to overwrite value stored in SRAM cell, we will set BL and -BL according to our data (To store bit 0 - set BL and unset -BL; to store bit 1 - set -BL and unset BL); then the write is enabled for current set (line) of cells (WL is on; it will open M5 and M6). After opening of M5 and M6, BL and -BL will change state of bistable flip-flop (like in [SR-latch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch_(electronic)#Simple_set-reset_latches)). So, new value is written and old value is discarded (by leaking charge into BL and -BL).

Comment: Wow! Landauer's principle is cool! Never thought of it this way.

Comment: You should know that it is still bit controversial. It is a lower limit and it is < 2/100 (worst case estimation) of Wt for modern CPUs (with dozens of classic Wt). But it is major limiting factor of quantum computers (if you will irreversibly rewrite quantum register, it will be heated up and lose quantum properties). So [Quantum gates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate) have equal number of input and output, and any computation can be restored (inverted) from final state back into starting state.